# Android: Dynamically add buttons after spinner item selected

Tags: java, android, button, spinner

bit of a rough time getting this to work and its an understanding piece on my end...

If i have a spinner item that contains the text "The [item] is [color]" and upon selecting this, I would like it to populate a... tablerow or something like that(or just a relativelayout)... with buttons and there would be two buttons, [item] and [color], stacked one on the other.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentview, View arg1, int position, long id) 
{

    final TableLayout t1 = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.button_items);
    final TableRow tr = new TableRow(t1.getContext());
ArrayList<String> words = Create_ArrayList(R.raw.titles);
```

// Create_ArrayList just parses known words like the [item] and [color] items and puts them into an array... for enumeration purposes later on.

```
String sentence = (String) spin.getSelectedItem();

    if(sentence.contains("[item]"))
    {
        String line = words.get(1);
        ArrayList<String> x = getParts(line);
```

//arraylist should just be [item] and [color] at this point...

```
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Integer.toString(x.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    for(int i = 0; i<x.size(); i++)
    {
              Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), x.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Button btn = new Button(tr.getContext());
       btn.setText(x.get(i));
       btn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
       tr.addView(btn);
       t1.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }   
}
}
```

but i keep getting...

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first
```

and the buttons dont show up... app just crashes... into a mountain.

help is much appreciated...  Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code block

```
final TableLayout t1 = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.button_items);
```

you already have the view of t1, but again in the third code block you are adding the view

```
tr.addView(btn);
       t1.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

that is the reason for your exception.

When a View is allready used (e.g., you got it with findViewById, don't use addView on it). When you want to add a view, use addView with a NEW view. You can add several of these new views to one view, but you cannot add that one view multiple times.

This is what i found in some other post

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply on this. I eventually figured it out after taking a few minutes to think about the problem a little bit deeper.     I found that just using t1.addView(btn, new params... blah blah) worked but everything else was not necessary anyhow.  I definitely do accept this answer though, thank you so much for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are adding the same button over and over to the same table row.  You could use an array of buttons,

```
btns = new Button[]{button1, button2, etc...}
```

and then say:

```
for(int i = 0; i < x.size() ; i++ ){
     btn[i] = new Button(tr.getContext());
     btn[i].setText(x.get(i));
     tr.addView(btn[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I didn't need to change anything with the buttons, it seemed to take it just fine.  It was just a matter of popping them into the TableView.  Thanks again!